# Finding the stationary points of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question that I need help with.

How do I find the stationary points of the following function?

$$y = \frac{4x^3}{(x-1)^2}$$

I differentiated the function and got

$$\begin{align}
y' &= 3x^3-12x^2 \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align}$$

Don't know what to do now.

Comment: Please use latex.. See here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, your differential is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a stationary point is a point $x$ for which $f'(x) = 0$.
I think your derivative is not correct. Using the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), we get
$$f'(x) = \frac{4x^2(x-3)}{(x-1)^3}$$

Now you need to find when the derivative is $0$.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{4x^2(x-3)}{(x-1)^3} &= 0\implies\\
4x^2(x-3) &= 0\implies\\
x_{1,2} = 0,\quad x_3 &= 3
\end{align}$$

Observe that $x = 0$ is a solution *twice*. That means that at $x = 0$ the function has an stationary inflection point. On the other hand, $x 3$ can either be a point of minimum or maximum. To find out, we'll need to study the sign of $f'(x)$.

We have that
$$f'(x) > 0 \implies x < 1 \lor x > 3$$
so we deduce that $f$ is increasing in the interval $(-\infty, 1)\cup(3, +\infty)$ and decreasing on $(1, 3)$.

Therefore it must be that $x = 3$ is a local point of minimum.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know how to do these types of questions, but I tripped up on the differentiation and so got confused. thanks again.

Comment: @unknownDude: I'm happy to have been of help. You could accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the answer votes. If you have any other doubts I'll be happy to respond.